# Another thing keep checkbox checked after refresh/reload page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here are many solutions of checkbox keep checked but in this method these solution does not work.
I've trying in `AdminLTE` to keep layout-options work after reload the page, but the whole coding of layout-option comes from jquery and I'm not comforted in jquery, can you tell me how can fix. I have used these codes...

### demo.js

send views of layout options..

```
// Layout options
$demoSettings.append(
    '<h4 class="control-sidebar-heading">'
    + 'Layout Options'
    + '</h4>'
    // Fixed layout
    + '<div class="form-group">'
    + '<label class="control-sidebar-subheading">'
    + '<input type="checkbox" data-layout="fixed"class="pull-right" name="fixed_layout"/> '
    + 'Fixed layout'
    + '</label>'
    + '<p>Activate the fixed layout. You can\'t use fixed and boxed layouts together</p>'
    + '</div>'
    // Boxed layout
    + '<div class="form-group">'
    + '<label class="control-sidebar-subheading">'
    + '<input type="checkbox"data-layout="layout-boxed" class="pull-right" name="boxed_layout"/> '
    + 'Boxed Layout'
    + '</label>'
    + '<p>Activate the boxed layout</p>'
    + '</div>'
    // Sidebar Toggle
    + '<div class="form-group">'
    + '<label class="control-sidebar-subheading">'
    + '<input type="checkbox"data-layout="sidebar-collapse"class="pull-right" name="toggle_sidebar"/> '
    + 'Toggle Sidebar'
    + '</label>'
    + '<p>Toggle the left sidebar\'s state (open or collapse)</p>'
    + '</div>'
    // Sidebar mini expand on hover toggle
    + '<div class="form-group">'
    + '<label class="control-sidebar-subheading">'
    + '<input type="checkbox"data-enable="expandOnHover"class="pull-right" name="sidebar_hover"/> '
    + 'Sidebar Expand on Hover'
    + '</label>'
    + '<p>Let the sidebar mini expand on hover</p>'
    + '</div>'
    // Control Sidebar Toggle
    + '<div class="form-group">'
    + '<label class="control-sidebar-subheading">'
    + '<input type="checkbox"data-controlsidebar="control-sidebar-open"class="pull-right" name="toggle_slide"/> '
    + 'Toggle Right Sidebar Slide'
    + '</label>'
    + '<p>Toggle between slide over content and push content effects</p>'
    + '</div>'
    // Control Sidebar Skin Toggle
    + '<div class="form-group">'
    + '<label class="control-sidebar-subheading">'
    + '<input type="checkbox"data-sidebarskin="toggle"class="pull-right" name="toggle_skin"/> '
    + 'Toggle Right Sidebar Skin'
    + '</label>'
    + '<p>Toggle between dark and light skins for the right sidebar</p>'
    + '</div>'
)
var $skinsList = $('<ul />', {'class': 'list-unstyled clearfix'})
```

I've Using jquery for checkbox keep checked, 
 It works on other single HTML pages, but here i do not understand how to do this...

```
(function() {
var cbstate;
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  cbstate = JSON.parse(localStorage['CBState'] || '{}');
  for(var i in cbstate) {
    var el = document.querySelector('input[name="' + i + '"]');
    if (el) el.checked = true;
  }

  var cb = document.getElementsByClassName('pull-right');
  for(var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {
    cb[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      if (this.checked) {
        cbstate[this.name] = true;
      }
      else if (cbstate[this.name]) {
        delete cbstate[this.name];
      }
      localStorage.CBState = JSON.stringify(cbstate);
    });
  }
});
})();  

      
})
```

[image: AdminLTE Home]

Comment: in your given code check-boxes have name like `toggle_sidebar, sidebar_hover,toggle_slide,toggle_skin` and you are doing  `var el = document.querySelector('input[name="' + i + '"]');` . so how it will work?

Comment: @AlivetoDie okay sir, so what i need to change, and if i change it will not work too,